# Java insertar objetos en una LinkedList y mostrarlos en pantalla

Tags: java

Estoy intentando desarrollar un programa que simule una especie de armario o despensa. Para realizar dicho ejercicio he desarrollado dos clases. La primera clase es la clase Comida. La cuál he desarrollado para poder crearme objetos de esta clase. La segunda clase que estoy haciendo es la clase armario. La clase armario tiene como atributos un nombre de tipo String y una LinkedList en la que iré añadiendo objetos de la clase Comida. Bien pues lo que quiero hacer es que al añadir un objeto Comida al armario se añada si no hay ningún objeto que tenga las mismas características en la LinkedList pero si ya existe uno igual pues lo que se haría sería sumarse a la cantidad de dicho objeto Comida. A continuación es dejo la clase Comida desarrollada por mi y el método addProducto de la clase Armario que he desarrollado pero que no me termina de funcionar:

Clase Comida:

````
public class Comida {
    
    private String nombre;
    private String tipo;
    private boolean procesado;
    private int cantidad;
    
    public Comida (String nombre, String tipo, int cantidad, boolean procesado) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.tipo = tipo;
        this.cantidad = cantidad;
        this.procesado = procesado;
    }
    
    public void setNombre (String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }
    
    public void setTipo (String tipo) {
        this.tipo = tipo;
    }
    
    public void setCantidad (int cantidad) {
        this.cantidad = cantidad;
    }
    
    public void procesado (boolean procesado) {
        this.procesado = procesado;
    }
    
    public String getNombre () {
        return this.nombre;
    }
    
    public String getTipo () {
        return this.tipo;
    }
    
    public int getCantidad () {
        return this.cantidad;
    }
    
    public boolean getProcesado () {
        return this.procesado;
    }
    
    public String toString () {
        String res = "";
        res += "Producto: " + this.nombre + " Tipo: " + this.tipo + " Cantidad: " + this.cantidad + " Procesado: ";
        if (procesado == true) {
            res += "Si";
        }else {
            res+= "No";
        }
        return res;
    }
}´´´

Método addProducto de la clase Armario:
```package armario;
import java.util.*;

public class Armario {
    
    private String nombre;
    private LinkedList<Comida> contenido;
    
    public Armario (String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        contenido = new LinkedList<Comida>();
    }
    
    public void addProducto (Comida food) {
        for (int i = 0; i < contenido.size(); i++) {
            if(contenido.get(i).getNombre().equals(food.getNombre())) {
                int nuevaCant = contenido.get(i).getCantidad() + food.getCantidad();
                contenido.get(i).setCantidad(nuevaCant);
                break;
            }else if(!contenido.get(i).getNombre().equals(food.getNombre())) {
                contenido.add(food);
            }
        }
    }

Y el main que estoy utilizando:

```public static void main (String [] args) {
        Comida c1 = new Comida("Platano", "Fruta", 5, false);
        Comida c2 = new Comida("Chocolate", "Dulces", 2, true);
        Comida c3 = new Comida("Leche", "Lacteo", 10, false);
        Comida c4 = new Comida("Galletas", "Dulces", 7, true);
        Comida c5 = new Comida("Awakate", "Fruta", 4, false);
        Comida c6 = new Comida("Awakate", "Fruta", 4, false);
        
        Armario a = new Armario("Mi Armario");
        
        a.addProducto(c1);
        a.addProducto(c2);
        a.addProducto(c3);
        a.addProducto(c4);
        a.addProducto(c5);
        a.addProducto(c6);
        
        System.out.println(a.toString());
        
        
        
    }
````

Comment: Cuando algo no funciona, claramente explica que pasa (tiene un error? que hace exactamente para decir no funciona?)...

Comment: En este caso, tendrias que haber dicho que te agregaba elementos de mas...

Comment: Veo un **error de diseño en tu método `addProducto()`**, fatigas la memoria recorriendo la lista caaaada vez que se vaya a agregar un producto. En términos reales esto equivaldría a sacar del armario todos los productos cada vez que haya uno nuevo y ponerlos otra vez en el armario. Es algo un poco tonto ¿no? Pues eso es lo que hace el `for` en tu método. Es mejor verificar si ese producto existe, si existe le sumas uno, si no existe lo agregas a la lista.

Answer (score 2):

Leamos lo que hace tu metodo addProducto (que nombre raro.. add en ingles, producto en español.. o es addproduct o es agregarproducto)...

```
public void addProducto (Comida food) {
    //recorremos la lista que tiene este estante
    for (int i = 0; i < contenido.size(); i++) {
        //me fijo si el producto es igual al que estoy mirando de esta lista
        if(contenido.get(i).getNombre().equals(food.getNombre())) {
            //es el mismo! lo sumo aca 
            int nuevaCant = contenido.get(i).getCantidad() + food.getCantidad();
            contenido.get(i).setCantidad(nuevaCant);
            //y salgo del for...
            break;
        //Me fijo si es distinto al producto que estoy mirando... 
        //pensandolo bien, si no era igual **ES DISTINTO** siempre
        }else if(!contenido.get(i).getNombre().equals(food.getNombre())) {
            //Lo agrego ... siempre??? 
            contenido.add(food);
        }
    }
}
```

Ahora, luego de ver que tu logica esta mal (se entiende?) escribamos algo que funcione mas logicamente...

```
public void addProducto (Comida food) {
    int indice = -1;
    //recorremos la lista que tiene este estante
    for (int i = 0; i < contenido.size(); i++) {
        //me fijo si el producto es igual al que estoy mirando de esta lista
        if(contenido.get(i).getNombre().equals(food.getNombre())) {
            indice = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (indice == -1) {
        //no existe, agrego
        contenido.add(food);
    } else {
        int nuevaCant = contenido.get(i).getCantidad() + food.getCantidad();
        contenido.get(i).setCantidad(nuevaCant);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yo dotaría a la clase de un método para verificar si el producto existe: `productExists()` recorrer todo el armario cada vez es un error de diseño.

Comment: @A.Cedano totalmente de acuerdo, yo solo corregi la logica de ese metodo... pero si.. eso seria una solucion mejor...

Comment: igual, @A.Cedano es una lista doble, y siempre de alguna u otra forma la vas a recorrer para saber si el item esta o no... no hay otra forma...

Comment: No hay que recorrerla. Se puede verificar si el elemento existe y aumentar la cantidad sin tener que andar por todo el armario. Imagina algo parecido en un gran almacén donde tienes que sacar todos los productos de cajas y otros contenedores para ver si un nuevo producto existe, es algo absurdo y es lo significa ese for en el método. Otra cosa es si el tipo de objeto que se usa para lo que se quiere hacer sea el más adecuado...

Comment: @A.Cedano uses el metodo que uses, la unica forma de saber si un elemento pertenece o esta en una coleccion es recorriendola. Aunque sea internamente, sin que hagas el for a mano se va a recorre...

Comment: Se puede verificar si la key existe o no directamente.

Comment: @A.Cedano para verificar eso, uses el metodo que uses, se recorre la lista.. fijate en las implementaciones de los metodos...

Comment: [Mira esto](https://beginnersbook.com/2014/07/java-check-if-a-particular-element-exists-in-linkedlist-example/). Sigo pensando que es absurdo tener que recorrer toda la lista.

Comment: @A.Cedano Claro, pero te fijaste que hace contains internamente? hace un while recorriendo la lista hasta que lo encuentra o devuelve null.. o sea, lo recorre.. aunque no aca afuera...

Comment: Ok. Entiendo. Si `contains` hay que usarlo ¿no? Para el `for` tienes que declarar objetos adicionales para controlar el índice por ejemplo.

Comment: @A.Cedano ahi, la discusion gira para otro lado y es otra cosa, mas interesante, jugosa y ahi si te doy toda la razon del mundo... ;) pero una lista doblemente enlazada se recorre siempre para ubicar un elemento :)

Answer (score 0):

Que error tienes? Yo veo lo siguiente: Sucede que tu metodo addProducto si hace 10 vueltas y en todas es diferente entonces va agregar el producto esa cantidad de veces, ya que no se interrumpe el for en ningún momento si hay coincidencia.

podrías:

```
public void addProducto (Comida foodR) { //R de recibido
    boolean repetido=false;
    for (Comida comida:contenido) {
        if(comida.getNombre().equals(foodR.getNombre()) && repetido == false) {
            repetido=true;
            break;
        }
    }
       if(repetido==true){
         comida.setCantidad(comida.getCantidad()+foodR.getCantidad());
       }else{
          contenido.add(foodR);
       }
   
}
```

La intención es verificar si se encuentra en tu dispensa dicha Comida, la cual la comparas con el Nombre aunque para hacerlo mas preciso podrías comparar tanto el tipo como el nombre, quizás tengas 2 nombres iguales pero de tipos diferentes.

Comment: Hay un gravísimo error de diseño en ese `for`. Es como sacar todos los productos del armario para volverlos a meter. ¿Por qué no verificar directamente si el producto existe? La clase incluso debería tener un método para tales fines.

Comment: El problema que tengo es que al hacerlo de la forma que lo he hecho yo al ejecutar el metodo toString() en el main es decir, System.out.println(a.toString()) no se me muestran los objetos de tipo Comida que deberían de haberse añadido a la lista.

Comment: @A.Cedano es peor, vuelve a agregar los mismos items que ya estaban una y otra vez...

Comment: @Daniel ese seria otro problema diferente ademas de lo que te estamos mostrando...

Comment: ah y para colmo este metodo, al tener el break, no agrega el elemento repetido. Esta mal.

Comment: correcto me percaté del fallo luego del post. Gracias por notificar

Answer (score 0):

También he desarrollado el método de esta otra forma:

```
        Iterator ite = contenido.iterator();
        while (ite.hasNext()) {
            Comida aux = (Comida) ite.next();
            if (aux.getNombre().equals(food.getNombre())) {
                int nuevaCant = aux.getCantidad() + food.getCantidad();
                aux.setCantidad(nuevaCant);
            }
        }
        contenido.add(food);
    }
´´´
Y al tratar de mostrarlo por pantalla he conseguido que se me sumen las cantidades bien pero se me muestran los Awakates dos veces. La primera vez con la cantidad de 8 y la segunda vez con la cantidad de 4.

P.D: Este ejercicio lo hago con la intención de aprender más sobre java y por eso pongo nombres absurdos o mal escritos. Gracias igualmente por comentármelo :D
```

Comment: no es tu primera pregunta, sabes que el area de respuestas es solo para respuestas.. ninguna de las respuestas dadas te sirve? deja comentarios en las mismas y aclara porque....

Comment: Y borra esta publicacion que no es una respuesta...

Answer (score 0):

Tras estar trabajando en esto he conseguido encontrar una solución. Este es el código que he hecho:

```
        Iterator ite = contenido.iterator();
        if (contenido.contains(food)) {
            while (ite.hasNext()) {
                Comida aux = (Comida) ite.next();
                if (aux.getNombre().equals(food.getNombre())) {
                    int nuevaCant = aux.getCantidad() + food.getCantidad();
                    aux.setCantidad(nuevaCant);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }else {
            contenido.add(food);
        }
    }´´´

El único problema que le veo ahora es que no puedo crear dos objetos que sean exactamente iguales porque se me añadirían ambos a la lista. Por ejemplo:
Comida c5 = new Comida("Awakate", "Fruta", 4, false);
Comida c6 = new Comida("Awakate", "Fruta", 4, false);

Son dos objetos con nombres diferentes pero realmente son lo mismo. Aún así no tendría sentido crearse dos objetos iguales pero con diferente nombre, no?
```